# Trying insert an int in a text file name is not working

Tags: ofstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

string name;
int n = 1;
// Account Number
int main()
{
    cout << "What is your full name? : ";
    cin >> name;

    ofstream myfile;

    filec:
    //Go to file creation
    myfile.open ("account" << n << ".txt");
    myfile << "Account Holder: " << name << endl;
    myfile.close();
}
```

As seen i attempt to create files with different numbers at the end at each unique fail but i keep getting an error on myfile.open line

Answer (score 0):

When ofstream uses open, it expects a String (or more specifically a char*) as its input. You have to convert n into a string. Furthermore, you need to append the different parts of the string instead of using the overloaded operator <<, as none of its operations will give you the desired result of a single string. If you are using c++11, to_string is included in the std library and you can simply use the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

string name;
int n = 1;
// Account Number
int main()
{
    cout << "What is your full name? : ";
    cin >> name;

    ofstream myfile;

    filec:
    //Go to file creation
    myfile.open("account" + to_string(n) + ".txt");
    myfile << "Account Holder: " << name << endl;
    myfile.close();
}
```